# Creating a desktop shortcut out of a key combination?

Tags: windows, vbscript, keyboard, desktop, shortcut

I need a little desktop shortcut that I could click with a mouse. It needs to perform the action <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I was told that I could build a .VBS file to create a desktop shortcut but I have absolutely no idea how to do so. I'm clueless about coding and this sort of tech stuff.

All I could find was this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^+{ESCAPE}"
```

Theoretically I could just replace those values for <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but I don't know their correspondent strings.

So, how can I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're running Windows 7, the shortcut you're looking for is that little transparent box in the lower right hand corner of the screen.

Comment: Yes I'm aware. However, I'm on windows 8, using a tablet and running a program in full-screen mode. That means I can't access the task bar (don't know if it's windows 8's fault, the tablet itself or the program). 

If I manage to create that clickable shortcut, all I need is to move it to windows 8's startscreen and voilà: I have a quick and efficient way to access my desktop without a keyboard/taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that, why not try:

```
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.MinimizeAll
Set Shell = nothing
```

Or maybe:

```
set Shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.ToggleDesktop
Set Shell = nothing
```

I don't have a Win 8 machine to test with right now. Let me know if it works.

Comment: You ARE THE MAN. Just as microsoft should've implemented their desktop tile! Thanks a lot!